# Generate a unique query string value in a URL when NFC chip is scanned?

Tags: nfc

I'm very new to NFC here. I am working on a project as part of which we are looking to do "check-ins" at a clients locations. We postulate we can use NFC tags so that people can scan them with their phones and easily "check in." The process after scanning would be to send the user to a URL such as `example.com/check-in?location=PA&uniqueSerial=1234567`.

Is there a way to get a unique serial number to place into the URL on each scan?

What I want to do is verify that the user has actually scanned the tag. What I don't want to happen is have users save the URL from the NFC tag and reload it again to create another "check-in."

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is off topic and too generic, though I have given some possibilities in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are some fairly 'off the shelf' NFC chips that can do this. These 'authentication' NFC Tags are typically used for product authentication / counterfeit protection, etc. Example of use case on [Seritag's website](https://learn.seritag.com/tech/nfc-tag-authentication-explained)

However, I can't see that you'd actually need the backend auth to do what you want. Each time the tag is scanned it will generate a new unique auth code and as long as you log any previous codes then the user will always need the next one. Without the backend auth system it wouldn't stop the user just making up a new code but it depends how secure you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an identical requirement to [Prevent URL obtained from NFC from being shared or accessed remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59431120/2373819)

And the answer is No,Yes and to some extent.

It depends on if you want to use a custom written App to read the cards or want to rely on the devices inbuilt behaviours to load the URL.

Most standard NFC tags just read and write to some EPROM data chips, so the data is static on the card, while most cards have a unique serial number this is still static data.

The possibilities are:-

1) Store a static URL in an NDEF message on the card that causes the device to load it in it's own browser - the URL is static and visible to the user for store and re-use. (That's the No response)

2) Write an App to read the cards, the URL can then be hidden from the user but still it will be unique to the card and static, but a determined person with the knowledge could work out the URL. (That's to some extent answer)

With Android you could use and AAR NDEF record to prompt the user to download the App if they don't have it already, not sure it this can be done on other devices.

2a) as 2) but then use the time or other methods to crypto hash the unique ID in time as well to make it a one time code. Harder for people to reverse engineer to but depending on how you do it determines the difficulty. (That's to some extent answer)

3) Their are some advanced cards out their that can run custom programs (one is called JavaCards https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Card ), so you could write a program that generates a unique serial you want and then present it to the card reader device as a standard NDEF message that would launch the devices browser to this dynamic URL. (This is a Yes response but it very very advanced)

4) Instead of a NFC card being read from, you could have a smartphone with an App running Host Card Emulation software (or other device with a USB reader/writer might also be able to do Host Card Emulation). This is like option 3 in that the program that generates a unique serial you want and then present it to the card reader device as a standard NDEF message that would launch the devices browser to this dynamic URL.

This of course requires the device to be secured and powered. (This is a Yes response, but has drawback that it is not as cheap as a NFC card and needs it's own power supply and is advanced in terms of programming).